# Im Triying to Color the users choice , for example thi, if he choices 1 then it'll change to "X" but i want to change the color of that X as well how?

Tags: c#

This is my Code :( , This is what i am triying to do so far it works but i neeed these colors things to light it up please if somoene can help me

```
namespace TIC_TAC_TOE
{

    class Program
    {
        static char[] arr = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        static int player = 1; //By default player 1 is set
        static int choice;
     
       static int flag = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {
                
                Console.Clear();// whenever loop will be again start then screen will be clear
                
                Console.WriteLine("Player1:X and Player2:O");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                if (player % 2 == 0)//checking the chance of the player
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 Chance");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 Chance");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Board();// calling the board Function
                try
                {
                    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("System Format Exepcion Dont Do that Again or you Cannot Continue The Program \n");
                }


                //Taking users choice
                // checking that position where user want to run is marked (with X or O) or not
                try
                {

                    if (arr[choice] != 'X' && arr[choice] != 'O')
                    {
                        if (player % 2 == 0) //if chance is of player 2 then mark O else mark X
                        {
                            arr[choice] = 'O';
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;  
                            player++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                            arr[choice] = 'X';
                            
                            player++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    //If there is any possition where user want to run
                    //and that is already marked then show message and load board again
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry the row {0} is already marked with {1}", choice, arr[choice]);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please wait 4 second board is loading again.....");
                        Thread.Sleep(4000);//esto es el tiempo que tardara en reiniciarse 
                        //https:/learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-7.0
                       //       //aqui va doble barrita , solo que los comentarios no me dejan comentarla por eso la puse debajo
                    }
                    flag = CheckWin();// calling of check win
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IOFRE ");
                    
                }
                
            }
            while (flag != 1 && flag != -1);
            // This loop will be run until all cell of the grid is not marked
            //with X and O or some player is not win
            Console.Clear();// clearing the console
            Board();// getting filled board again

            if (flag == 1)
            // if flag value is 1 then someone has win or
            //means who played marked last time which has win
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player {0} has won", (player % 2) + 1);
            }
            else// if flag value is -1 the match will be draw and no one is winner
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Draw");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Board method which creats board
        private static void Board()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
            Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[4], arr[5], arr[6]);
            Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[7], arr[8], arr[9]);
            Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
        }
        //Checking that any player has won or not
        private static int CheckWin()
        {
            #region Horzontal Winning Condtion
            //Winning Condition For First Row
            if (arr[1] == arr[2] && arr[2] == arr[3])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            //Winning Condition For Second Row
            else if (arr[4] == arr[5] && arr[5] == arr[6])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            //Winning Condition For Third Row
            else if (arr[6] == arr[7] && arr[7] == arr[8])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            #endregion
            #region vertical Winning Condtion
            //Winning Condition For First Column
            else if (arr[1] == arr[4] && arr[4] == arr[7])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            //Winning Condition For Second Column
            else if (arr[2] == arr[5] && arr[5] == arr[8])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            //Winning Condition For Third Column
            else if (arr[3] == arr[6] && arr[6] == arr[9])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            #endregion
            #region Diagonal Winning Condition
            else if (arr[1] == arr[5] && arr[5] == arr[9])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (arr[3] == arr[5] && arr[5] == arr[7])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            #endregion
            #region Checking For Draw
            // If all the cells or values filled with X or O then any player has won the match
            else if (arr[1] != '1' && arr[2] != '2' && arr[3] != '3' && arr[4] != '4' && arr[5] != '5' && arr[6] != '6' && arr[7] != '7' && arr[8] != '8' && arr[9] != '9')
            {
                return -1;
            }
            #endregion
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the color of the users choice :( the background of foreground either of them works but i dont know how to do it :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted nearly 200 lines of code, most of which aren't really relevant to the question, which I believe is really just about changing aspects of the console display. It would really help if you'd rewrite this as a [mcve] - focus on *just* the issue at hand.

Comment: Unrelated, but why is your return type of `CheckWin` an int, returning `1` and `-1`?  Why not make the return type a `bool` and return `true` and `false`?

Comment: @rory.ap Did you notice the `return 0;` near the end of the method?

Comment: @SirRufo Okay fine, then `bool?`

Comment: Your Array just holds a character, not a color, so whenever you call `Board()` it's simply going to output the whole thing in whatever color combination was LAST SET for the Console. If you want the `X`s and `O`s to be DIFFERENT colors then you need to modify `Board()` so it changes the color before outputting each position. This means you're going to have to break up the lines in that method as you can't use a single `Console.WriteLine()` to output each row...

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above:

> Your Array just holds a character, not a color, so whenever you call
> Board() it's simply going to output the whole thing in whatever color
> combination was LAST SET for the Console. If you want the Xs and Os to
> be DIFFERENT colors then you need to modify Board() so it changes the
> color before outputting each position. This means you're going to have
> to break up the lines in that method as you can't use a single
> Console.WriteLine() to output each row...

*The below code is totally untested...

Change:

```
private static void Board()
{
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
    Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[4], arr[5], arr[6]);
    Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", arr[7], arr[8], arr[9]);
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
}
```

To:

```
private static void Board()
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black; 
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.Write    ("  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[1]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[2]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[3]);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.Write    ("  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[4]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[5]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[6]);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("_____|_____|_____ ");
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
    Console.Write    ("  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[7]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[8]);
    Console.Write    ("  |  ");
    OutputColoredChar(arr[9]);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("     |     |      ");
}

private static void OutputColoredChar(char c) {
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    if (c == 'X') {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }
    else if (c == 'O') {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; 
    }
    Console.Write(c);
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
}
```